# STM32 CubeIDE Could not connect to target problem

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, stm32cubeide, j-link

I'm trying to code the stm32g030f6p6 microprocessor using J-link using STM32 CubeIDE, I get the warning "Could not connect to target, Please check power, connection, and settings".

When I make the same connection to a card from the stm32F series, I can send the code successfully, where is the problem?

stm32g030f6p6

[image]

[image]

[image]

stm32f0..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary:** Your debugger doesn't support the STM32G030 (or any other STM32 MCU model newer than 2012).

---

You said:

> I'm trying to code the stm32g030f6p6 microprocessor using **J-link**

It's important to note that you aren't using an original J-Link; it's a J-Link *clone*, as shown by the taobao.com URL on the back of the board in your [photo from the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFpxa.jpg):

[image: Edited photo from the question highlighting the taobao URL]

Now let's look at the error message from the [IDE screenshot from the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M58d8.jpg):

[image: Edited screenshot from the question showing the firmware date in the J-Link clone]

The firmware running in the J-Link clone is dated Aug 22 **2012**. However the first version of J-Link firmware that I can find which supports any of the STM32G0 series, is version V6.40a dated **2018**-12-11 on [this page of release notes](https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink/ReleaseNotes_JLink.html) on the Segger website.

Therefore I expect that:

- Your J-Link clone is running firmware that is 6 years too old to recognise the STM32G0 series of MCUs.
- Since you are using a J-Link *clone*, the firmware downloading tool from Segger might detect that it is not a genuine J-Link. Therefore it might not allow you to install the new firmware which supports the STM32G0 series, into the J-Link clone debugger. (This detection of clone debuggers certainly used to be the case in the past, as a friend described a similar situation several years ago.)

---

You might ask: Why could the J-Link clone be used to program another MCU?

The other MCU is shown in the IDE screenshot as STM32F401CCUx. I couldn't find a release date for that specific MCU (the STM32F4 range seems to have been introduced in late 2011/early 2012). Since you can program that one, it shows that this older MCU is supported by the 2012 firmware on your debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I did not do good research. thank you again

Comment: your answer is not explaining anything. It would not go ahead after getting the IC number. It is not the case here (it simply does not connect at all). This programmer does not have the reset line which basically makes it unusable (not possible to connect under reset).

Comment: @0___________ - Perhaps I am wrong. I am remembering a friend's situation with a clone J-Link from several years ago, which could program an STM32F103 but not some newer STM32 (IIRC an STM32L something) - then he was able to update the firmware on the clone J-Link (difficult but not impossible in those days) and then the newer MCU could be programmed - sounds exactly the same as here (new MCU can't be programmed, but an older MCU *can* be programmed). But that was all many years ago and my memory isn't perfect.

Comment: (continued)   I respectfully disagree that lacking "connect under reset" makes the clone J-Link *unusable* - note that the OP can use the same J-Link clone to program an older STM32 model, proving that functionality is not *always* required (it can be needed in *some* situations, yes, but not all). As always on Stack Exchange, if you have a better answer, please do write it. I will happily learn from, and upvote, an answer which is better than one I've written.